# React Map Array of Object with Nested Object

Tags: javascript

In react I would like to display id and name of category. How to achieve this assuming the object below is somehow hard for me to understand.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "category": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "CALZATURA",
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "category": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "PELLETTERIA",
        }
    }
]
```

```
dataItems.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{item.title}</h1>
      {category.map((c, i) => (
        <div>
          <p>{c.name}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  Generally one would use `.map()` in a React render function to output elements from an array.  The question's title implies that you already know this.  So where are you stuck?

Comment: dataItems.map((item, index) => {
        return ( <div>
            <h1>{item.title}</h1>
            { category.map((c, i) => <div>
            <p>{c.name}</p>
            </div>)}
          </div>
        )
      })

Comment: Relevant code belongs in the question, not in comments.  Please update the question to include your attempt and describe specifically what isn't working as expected.  (At a glance, the code in that comment should fail because you're trying to use a variable called `category` which was never defined.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your array is stored in a variable named `const categories = [...];`.

```js
return (
  <div>
    {categories.map((category) => (
      <div>
        <span>{category.id}</span>
        <span>{category.category.name}</span>
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
)
```